# spring record default value on a collection/map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this simple configuration:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("dummy")
public record TestRecord(@DefaultValue Set<String> values, @DefaultValue("default") String one) {
}
```

This does not work and fails with : `Parameter of type java.util.Set<java.lang.String> must have a non-empty default value.`

What I would like to get as a default value is a *empty* `Set`. Of course as a workaround, I can:

```
public Set<String> values() {
    return values == null ? Set.of() : values;
}
```

but considering there are any of these default collections/maps, is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32564). It was fixe, also, when I reported it.